# How to include version information to module dependency in package.json from self hosted git repository

Tags: node.js, git, npm, npm-install

I am using this dependency declaration in my `package.json` which works excelent.

`"node-mylib": "git+http://tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_git/node-mylib"`

I wonder how to specify version information if I would publish via npm like this `"node-mylib": "^2.3.5"` in combination with a GIT repository source.

I combine `npm version patch` in my deploy script so there exists different version tags. Can we specify version in module dependency over self hosted git repositories?

Answer (score 0):

`git show-ref --tags -d` shows my tags including hash values. It is possible to referenc a special commit appending `#GIT_COMMIT_HASH` to the git url.